# Problem with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to use z-index to layer a button and a div. The button appears behind the div, while according to z-index it should be in front of it. Here is the style elements associated with the button & div as captured by Firebug:

Note that the button has a z-index of 2, the div has a z-index of 1, and both are position:relative.

Full HTML is in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/M82TZW2P).

Comment: Since both elements are positioned and have z-index, we're going to have to see HTML to sort this one out.

Comment: @dclowd9901 - the elements are created via javascript. How do I capture a static HTML?

Comment: 1 and 2 are probably not good values to use for z-index, especially for testing. Try 1000 and 2000 and see if that changes anything.

Comment: "View source" in your test browser, go to the elements in question and copypasta.

Comment: @Robusto - tried 1000 & 2000, didn't change a thing.
@dclowd9901 - I'm using Firefox and view source doesn't see the changes from javascript ... but I managed to capture it with Firebug : http://pastebin.com/M82TZW2P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

z-index is a relative, not an absolute value.

An object with z-index 10 billion will not appear on top of all elements on the page, only on top of other elements in the same *stacking context*

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex

http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp

In the CSS hierarchy you posted, it looks like the button and div are contained in different elements (`#note18` and `#note19`), so you'll have to make sure that those elements aren't creating different stacking contexts which will make any z-indexes for elements inside them irrelevant to each other.

Comment: Hmm .. interesting, I didn't know that.

How would you suggest I proceed in "making sure those elements aren't creating different contexts..." ?

Comment: I'm reading through what you linked to, I guess the answer is there but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: I played around with the second link, and found no easy way to do this while keeping relative positions anywhere in above in the hierarchy. OK, so now I understand why this is happening - but how can I get the desired effect?

Comment: When I copied your pastebin code, removing the z-index from the .sticky class allowed the buttons to show on top of neighbouring cells.

Comment: Thanks @GApple - I ended up leaving only the z-index for the button itself, and this works perfectly.